# How to configure a Bool Stream in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am willing to force a reload of a `collectionView` when new content is fetched from a web-service while using `RxSwift`. I can't figure out why I don't receive an event on newContent with the following code when my onComplete closure is properly called.

```
class ListingView : UIView {

    var newContentStream: Observable<Bool>?
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    weak var viewModel: ListingViewModel?

    func bind(viewModel: ListingViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func configure() {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }

        self.newContentStream = viewModel.newContent.asObservable()
        self.newContentStream!.subscribeNext { _ in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
    } 
}
```

and then within my viewModel:

```
class ListingViewModel {
    let dataSource = ListingViewDataSoure()
    var newContent = Variable(false)

    func mount() {
        let onComplete : ([item]? -> Void) = { [weak self] items  in
            self?.dataSource.items = items
            self?.newContent = Variable(true)
        }

        guard let URL = API.generateURL() else { return }
        Requestor.fetchAll(onComplete, fromURL: URL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `self?.newContent = Variable(true)` is replacing the `newContent` with an entirely **new** `Variable`, **after** you've already subscribed to the original here:

```
self.newContentStream = viewModel.newContent.asObservable()
self.newContentStream!.subscribeNext { ......
```

That subscription in your `UIView` is now listening to an `Observable` that no one is ever going to be sending a `Next` event on.

Instead, you should be sending out a `Next` event on the current (and only) `newContent` `Variable`/`Observable`:

```
self?.newContent.value = true
```

You could fix it and continue to use a `newContent` `Variable` and a `reloadData` call, however, I wouldn't recommend doing it like this.  Instead, check out [`RxDataSources`](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out with RxDataSources. How can i simply stream some bool event though if i shouldn't reset the newContent? Can i observe the datasource?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show you how.  But again, I wouldn't suggest doing it this way.

Comment: It works fine with your suggestion thanks - i will look into the RxDataSources as a next step now